# Own WinForms Control Flickers and Has Bad Performance

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, user-controls, flicker

I have two problems with an own user control which uses bitmaps:

1. It flickers if it's redrawn via .NET's 'Refresh' method.
2. It has a bad performance.

The control consists of three bitmaps:

- A static background image.
- A rotating rotor.
- Another image depending on rotor angle.

All used bitmaps have a resolution of 500x500 pixels. The control works like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t92gucestwdkx8z/StatorAndRotor.gif (it's a gif animation)

The user control should draw itself everytime it gets a new rotor angle. Therefore, it has a public property 'RotorAngle' which looks like this:

```
public double RotorAngle
{
    get { return mRotorAngle; }
    set
    {
        mRotorAngle = value;
        Refresh();
    }
}
```

`Refresh` raises the `Paint` event. The `OnPaint` event handler looks like this:

```
private void StatorAndRotor2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Draw the three bitmaps using a rotation matrix to rotate the rotor bitmap.
    Draw((float)mRotorAngle);
}
```

But when I use this code - which works well in other own user controls - the user control is not drawn at all if control is double buffered via `SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true)`. If I don't set this flag to true, the control flickers when being redrawn.

In control constructor I set:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
SetStyle(ControlStyles.ContainerControl, false);
// User control is not drawn if "OptimizedDoubleBuffer" is true.
// SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
```

First, I thought it flickers because the background is cleared everytime the control is drawn. Therefore, I set `SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true)`. But it didn't help.

So, why does it flicker? Other controls work very well with this setup. And why is the controly not drawn if `SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true)`.

I found out that the control does not flicker if I invoke my `Draw` method directly after changing the property `RotorAngle`:

```
public float RotorAngle
{
    get { return mRotorAngle; }
    set
    {
        mRotorAngle = value;
        Draw(mRotorAngle);
    }
}
```

But this results in a very bad performance, especially in full screen mode. It's not possible to update the control every 20 milliseconds. You can try it yourself. I will attach the complete Visual Studio 2008 solution below.

So, why it is such a bad performance? It's no problem to update other (own) controls every 20 milliseconds. Is it really just due to the bitmaps?

I created a simple visual Visual Studio 2008 solution to demonstrate the two problems:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mckmgysjxm0o9e0/WinFormsControlsTest.zip (289,3 KB)

There is an executable in directory `bin\Debug`.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't go into all the details now, but you need to look at double buffering. Fortunately it's very simple in 2008+ The way you are doing the refresh in the property is bad too.

Comment: Please don't double-buffer if your application might be used over remote desktop - see [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/01/03/508694.aspx). You can check if the current session is remote desktop with: `if (SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession) ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, per LarsTech's answer, you should use the `Graphics` context provided in the `PaintEventArgs`.  By calling `CreateGraphics()` inside the `Paint` handler, you prevent `OptimizedDoubleBuffer` from working correctly.

Second, in your SetStyle block, add:

```
SetStyle( ControlStyles.Opaque, true );
```

... to prevent the base class Control from filling in the background color before calling your Paint handler.

I tested this in your example project, it seemed to eliminate the flickering.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `CreateGraphics`, but use the Graphic object that was passed to you from the paint event:

I changed it like so and added a clear since resizing would show the ghost image:

```
private void Draw(float rotorAngle, Graphics graphics)
{
  graphics.Clear(SystemColors.Control);
  graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

  // yada-yada-yada

  // do not dispose since you did not create it:
  // graphics.Dispose();
}
```

called from:

```
private void StatorAndRotor2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  Draw((float)mRotorAngle, e.Graphics);
}
```

In the constructor, turn on double-buffering, but I think the transparency isn't needed:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
SetStyle(ControlStyles.ContainerControl, false);
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
//SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Drawing at screen on Paint event is a heavy operation. Doing paint on memory buffer is comparatively very fast.

[Double buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics) will improve the performance. Instead of drawing on paint graphics, create a new graphics, and do all drawing on it.

Once bitmap drawing is done, copy the entire bitmap to e.Graphics received from PaintEventArgs

[Flicker free drawing using GDI+ and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4646/Flicker-free-drawing-using-GDI-and-C)

Answer (score 0):

For my answer I took inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2608945/455904 and I nabbed stuff from [LarsTechs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10586330/455904) answer above.

To avoid having to regenerate the complete image on all OnPaints you can use a variable to hold the generated image.

```
private Bitmap mtexture;
```

Use Draw() to generate the texture

```
private void Draw(float rotorAngle)
{
    using (var bufferedGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(mtexture))
    {
        Rectangle imagePosition = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
        bufferedGraphics.DrawImage(mStator, imagePosition);
        bufferedGraphics.DrawImage(RotateImage(mRotor, mRotorAngle), imagePosition);

        float normedAngle = mRotorAngle % cDegreePerFullRevolution;

        if (normedAngle < 0)
            normedAngle += cDegreePerFullRevolution;

        if (normedAngle >= 330 || normedAngle <= 30)
            bufferedGraphics.DrawImage(mLED101, imagePosition);
        if (normedAngle > 30 && normedAngle < 90)
            bufferedGraphics.DrawImage(mLED001, imagePosition);
        if (normedAngle >= 90 && normedAngle <= 150)
            bufferedGraphics.DrawImage(mLED011, imagePosition);
        if (normedAngle > 150 && normedAngle < 210)
            bufferedGraphics.DrawImage(mLED010, imagePosition);
        if (normedAngle >= 210 && normedAngle <= 270)
            bufferedGraphics.DrawImage(mLED110, imagePosition);
        if (normedAngle > 270 && normedAngle < 330)
            bufferedGraphics.DrawImage(mLED100, imagePosition);
    }
}
```

Have the override of OnPaint draw the texture on your control

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    Rectangle imagePosition = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(mtexture, imagePosition);
}
```

Override OnInvalidated() to Draw() the texture when needed

```
protected override void OnInvalidated(InvalidateEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInvalidated(e);

    if (mtexture != null)
    {
        mtexture.Dispose();
        mtexture = null;
    }

    mtexture = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
    Draw(mRotorAngle);
}
```

Instead of calling Draw invalidate the image. This will cause it to repaint using OnInvalidated and OnPaint.

```
public float RotorAngle
{
    get { return mRotorAngle; }
    set
    {
        mRotorAngle = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

I hope I got all of it in there :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help.

Flickering is solved. :)

Now, I follow [LarsTech's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10586330/1393897) suggestion and use the `Graphics` object from `PaintEventArgs`.

Thanks [lnmx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797538/lnmx) for the hint that `CreateGraphics()` inside `Paint` handler prevents the correct function of `OptimizedDoubleBuffer`. This explains the flickering problem even if `OptimizedDoubleBuffer` was enabled. I didn't know that and I also haven't found this at [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401). In my previous controls, I have also used the `Graphics` object from `PaintEventArgs`.

Thanks [Sallow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455904/sallow) for your efforts. I will test your code today and I will give feedback. I hope this will improve performance because there is still a performance issue - despite correct double buffering.

There was still another performance problem in my original code.

Changed

```
graphics.DrawImage(mStator, imagePosition);
graphics.DrawImage(RotateImage(mRotor, rotorAngle), imagePosition);
```

to

```
graphics.DrawImage(mStator, imagePosition);
Bitmap rotatedImage = RotateImage(mRotor, rotorAngle);
graphics.DrawImage(rotatedImage, imagePosition);
rotatedImage.Dispose(); // Important, otherwise the RAM will be flushed with bitmaps.
```