# C# Better way to scroll custom graphic to reduce flickering

Tags: c#, scroll, flicker, reduce, graphic

I am busy developing an C# win form application, that draws a graphical representation of a database structure in a hierarchical structure.

Everything is working fine, I just have a problem with scrolling.  It has a bad flickering problem.

I have researched the following:

[C# graphics flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608909/c-sharp-graphics-flickering)

Call `Invalidate()` when you want to refresh the surface (has helped a lot but still a little of a lag)

Also to set `DoubleBuffered` property to True (Problem with this I get an `ArgumentException` thrown with message "Parameter is not valid.".  But I can set `DoubleBuffered` to true on my main form)

**Detail on my design**

I have two class `Node` and `Link` they both have `GraphicsPath` members, and they both have a `public void Draw(Graphics g)` method to draw themselves.

I also have a user control call `StructureMap` that has overridden the `protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)` method, to loop through every `Node` calling it's draw function.  The looping is simple because the Parent Node is link to the children nodes by a `Link` object. All I have to do is call the parent node's draw method, and all its children nodes are also redrawn.

I am also preforming Hit testing the same way.

Is there maybe a better way? Why can't I have `DoubleBuffered` set to true on my user control?

PS: This is my first post, let me know how I did?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your flickering sound like it is caused by the amount of processing you have to do to draw the image.

One way to  alleviate this is to draw your model to an offscreen bitmap, then your paint/scroll etc just draw that bitmap to the screen.

Then only update the bitmap if your model changes.

Comment: I think bitmap can help a lot.  I also want to know can you do hit testing with bitmaps?  As I also want to animate my objects, want to be able to select and un-select them?

Comment: One way is to attach your image to PictureBox control, position the picture box inside a Panel with AutoScroll enabled. Use the various mouse events to get the position of mouse interactions.

Comment: I will have a look at this in the future, as for now I just working with my current design, because using bitmaps and PictureBox will be a redesign.  I think I will consider that in version 2 ;)

Answer (score 1):

The DoubleBuffered ArgumentException is probably caused due to the fact that you somewhere dispose the graphics object.

Also refer to this article; [What could cause Double Buffering to kill my app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134181/what-could-cause-double-buffering-to-kill-my-app)

Comment: You are right, that solved the DoubleBuffered issue. I thought you needed to Dispose the graphics object to prevent memory leaks.  But with DoubleBuffered on there is still a lag in scrolling.

Comment: @ZioN: that's because your paint routine is slow and that's an entirely different matter. feel free to ask another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Using bitmap as a background image will reduce flickering. Maybe like this :

```
 private Bitmap _backBuffer;
 private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
 {
      if (_backBuffer == null)
        {
            _backBuffer = new Bitmap(Form1.Width, Form1.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
        }
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(_backBuffer);

        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        drawSomething(g);

        //Copy the back buffer to the screen
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(_backBuffer, 0, 0);
        Form1.BackgroundImage = _backBuffer;
 }
```